# git checkout of branch to a nonexistent repository

Tags: git

I have a GitHub repository which I use for all my development projects. One of my customers recently asked me to switch to BitBucket instead and hook up with Jira.
During that process something went terribly wrong, and I decided to recover to my faithful GitHub.

Apparently I must have deleted some local git repositories, because all of the sudden I can't check out my 'development' branch, because it is already checked out in a nonexistent repository (or at least I can't find it).

As per now I have no waiting commits of local changes and everything. How do I do a reverse checkout on a nonexistent repository?

Edit: the output of:

```
git branch -vv
```

is:

```
  development f6822f0 (D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master_UserInterface)
+ origin      386d25f (D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master)
```

doing a `git checkout development` I get:

```
fatal: 'development' is already checked out
at 'D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master_UserInterface'
```

Problem is that these are not referring to my .git repository and as such not available.

Comment: What is the command you execute and the exact error message you get?

Comment: What do you mean by *nonexistent repository*?  In particular, show the *Git command you run*, and *its error output* (as text with cut-and-paste if possible; see [ask] for why not to use screenshots).

Comment: By 'non-existing repository' I mean a repository that is not available in the local dir

Comment: @torek By 'non-existing repository' I mean a repository that is not available in the local dir mainly because it as been deleted. :-( I think that the two repositories was created during the process of transferring my github repository to BitBucket. Under the recovery process they were deleted :-(

Comment: @SebDieBln dong a 'git branch -vv' I get development f6822f0 (D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master_UserInterface)  and + origin      386d25f (D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master)
doing a git checkout development I get fatal: 'development' is already checked out at 'D:/Development/VSJ5.WPF/.git_master_UserInterface'
Problem is that these are not referring to my .get reposotory and as such not available.. :-(

Comment: Did you create an extra git worktree?  Are you getting the error message `fatal: 'dev' is already checked out at '/home/john_doe/repo/my_extra_worktree'`. If so, you could probably just run `git worktree prune` in the main worktree to remove the stale linked worktree reference. But this only works if you still have the original local git repo. If the git repo is deleted, there is probably no way to recover (except cloning the repo anew from the remote). It is a little bit unclear if you deleted the git repo, or just deleted a linked worktree, though.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular situation I simply did a full delete of the current directory and cloned it again from the GitHub. In this process I had to accept, that some commits were not included, whick actual were committed before into the 'extra' repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Your output indicates that you *have not* (well, *had* not) deleted the *repository* at all.  Instead, you had used `git worktree add` to add a *secondary working tree* to your existing repository.  Use `git worktree list` to view your added working trees.  Remember that the `.git` folder is normally hidden from view, so that you don't see it; in added working trees, instead of a `.git` *folder*, Git stores a `.git` *file* that records where the actual repository is stored.<sup>1</sup>

In your own answer, you mention that you subsequently deleted the repository, and then re-cloned.  Deleting the repository destroys all the commits within that repository, including any commits being used by any added working trees.  There is no in-Git recovery for this, though any backups your system made (such as those made by macOS Time Machine) might be useful.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that **a Git repository** is, to a first approximation, just a pair of databases.  One holds all the commits and other supporting objects, which Git finds by their numbered hash IDs.  The other database holds names, where each name—branch name, tag name, or any other name—holds a single hash ID, of something important to be able to find.  For *branch* names, the stored hash ID is, by definition, the *latest commit on the branch*.  Making a new commit while being "on" some branch creates a new commit with a new, never-before-used hash ID, and then stores that new commit's hash ID into the branch name.

It's the *commits in the repository* that hold what you are interested in—or what Git, at least, cares about.  The *names* let you and Git find the "most interesting"—most recent—commits, from which Git will find earlier commits.  The stuff *inside* the commits is strictly read-only: your OS can remove the database entirely, but not even Git can overwrite any of the *commits stored within the database* (unless there are severe bugs in Git that is).

**You do not work in the Git repository.**  Instead, a standard clone copies *all the commits* of some *other* repository to a new repository, then creates one *branch name* in your own clone to remember your own latest commit (but starting with some copied commit, until you make a new commit).  This clone then has one standard *working tree* or *work-tree*.  Git copies the commit's files, which are read-only, *from* the commit *to* your working tree.  **You then work within your working tree.**  The main working tree, created at the time you create the clone, holds one checked-out branch.  Added working trees from `git worktree add` hold one other checked-out branch each.

A so-called *bare* clone is one with *no working tree*.  The usual purpose of such a clone is to act as a storage area for commits, with no work to be done on, with, or in any of the branches.  **Because a bare clone has no working tree, you cannot do any work on or with it.**  You can, however, add working trees *to* a bare clone.  This is not a mode of use that was anticipated by the core Git team and it does not work very well in current versions of Git, but this is being remedied now, around Git 2.35 or 2.36 or so.  There may still be some bugs in this area and I advise against doing this yet.

Your own `git branch -vv` output suggests that you had made a bare clone and then added two separate working trees.  Since this is not well supported yet, you may have run into some Git bugs.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth answer, which made me realize that I'm not as good at Git as I ought to be :-D I guess that your assumptions what has happened is very good. I just think that when doing the connection to BitBucket, it was that process that made the two worktrees. At least the names indicates that so, because they are are equal to something that is preset in BitBucket. Nevertheless, I mark your answer as the correct one. In not not only precise but also very informative and   educational. Thanks